# Accent error pdf conversion

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

I'm working with a google spreadsheet which is full of spanish names (words with accents as à,á,é,...). I use a google script for filling some cells and it works perfectly and the screen shows the names correctly.

But when i try to download as pdf or print as pdf the result file doesn't show the accent chars:

González (in the spreadsheet) --> Gonzlez in the pdf file.

Here a demo spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gx34BuBikNYq3NWJrHSs79Q-HR4o3ELZpWGmpFWxZT8/edit?usp=sharing

How I can solve this? Making my own pdf conversion script?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, can you share a demo spreadsheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gx34BuBikNYq3NWJrHSs79Q-HR4o3ELZpWGmpFWxZT8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those cells have the Font Familiy `Helvetica` that is not supported in Google Docs, you will see in the toolbar the font input is blank.

Choose a different font by select the cells in your spreadsheet you'd like to change then in the toolbar, click the name of the font you want, `Helvetica Neue` is available.

Since you mentioned the Spreadsheet is filled with Google App Script, you can set the font family of a range with [setFontFamily()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontfamilyfontfamily), but probably the Spreadsheet you're working on was imported and had that type of font.